# CHECK CONSTRAINT isn't identifying breaches of a constraint but DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS does

Tags: ssms, constraint, check-constraints

I have a table full of data and I have a constraint on a field in that table that is setup to ensure the total of 2 fields equals a 3rd field. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CHK_TOTALS] CHECK ([Field3] = [Field1] + [Field2])
```

If I then check this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_TOTALS]
```

No errors are returned, the operation executes successfully, therefore it is as though all rows are satisfying the constraint.

However, if I then execute `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS([Table1])` several rows are returned for constraint `CHK_TOTALS` showing that there are multiple breaches of the constraint.

I have checked the data and can confirm that `[Field1] + [Field2]` **does not** total `[Field3]` for all rows.

Why does the first check not identify these but using `DBCC CHECKCONSTRAINTS` does?

Comment: You're missing a check when you enable the constraint: `ALTER TABLE dbo.Table1 WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT CHK_TOTALS;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table1] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CHK_TOTALS]` enables the constraint for all future updates to the table. Since you originally created that constraint `WITH NOCHECK`, existing at that time rows were not verified, and this applies (emphasis mine):

> `WITH CHECK | WITH NOCHECK`
>
> Specifies whether the data in the table is or isn't validated against a newly added or re-enabled `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK` constraint. If you don't specify, `WITH CHECK` is assumed for new constraints, and **`WITH NOCHECK` is assumed for re-enabled constraints**.

In other words, unless you explicitly specify `WITH CHECK`, existing rows won't be verified when you enable the constraint.